# Rails couldn't find a valid model for Doorkeeper::AccessToken association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-7, doorkeeper

Added the below association in my user model:

```
has_many :access_tokens, class_name: 'Doorkeeper::AccessToken',
                           foreign_key: :resource_owner_id,
                           dependent: :delete_all
```

Getting this Error: `NameError (Rails couldn't find a valid model for Doorkeeper::AccessToken association. Please provide the :class_name option on the association declaration. If :class_name is already provided, make sure it's an ActiveRecord::Base subclass.

```
      raise NameError, msg
      ^^^^^):`
```

**Rails Version:** 7.0.3
**Ruby Version:** 3.1.2

Expected: No error of **Doorkeeper::AccessToken**

Comment: Have you also added a valid `belongs_to` in your `AccessToken` model?

Comment: Don't have any AceesToken model locally, I have directly accessed it through the doorkeeper gem.

Comment: Have you followed the instructions on the DoorKeeper documentation? It's hard to help when you've given little details on what you've done so far.